# Как вызвать функцию прямо без использывания объявления (JS)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, скрипт

Есть вот такой участок разметки:

```
<sometag class="body" id="body" onclick="EqApi.exit();" style="cursor:pointer">
</sometag >
```

Открывая консоль я пишу: ExitApi.exit.
На что получаю такой ответ:

```
(a){null!=this.u&&(a&&"string"==typeof a&&!/^[\s\xa0]*$/.test(a)?this.u.exit(ca(this.G,a)):this.u.exit())}
```

https://prnt.sc/jxlq1m
Теперь вопрос, как эту функцию засунуть в onlick.
Тоесть без явного использования Eq.exit();

Всем спасибо :)

Comment: Хорошо запутано, это вопрос как напиать вирус? В чём суть?

Comment: Я понимаю что моих знания и так нет. А Вы за вирусы говорите.

Comment: Чем вам не нравится явный вызов?

Comment: В контексте процедуры - никак. В контексте свойства - обьявляйте свойство вот https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty

Answer (score 1):

ExitApi.exit() вызывает метод exit() в контесте ExitApi. Так как по коду видно, что используются замыкания на какието переменные и свойства самого ExitApi, просто скопировать код и выполнить не получится.